Yaml Pipeline: Add condition for each environment to use a specific agent from the agent pool
I need to add the condition for each environment to use specific Agent.Name. For dev and sandbox environment it should be using the same Agent.Name "agent-dev"



Environment
Agent.Name




dev and sandbox
agent-dev


int
agent-int


preprod
agent-preprod


prod
agent-prod



Yaml code is shown below. How can I write the condition for dev and sandbox environment to use the same Agent.Name "agent-dev"?
pool:
  vmImage: 'linux'

trigger: none

parameters:
  - name: env
    values:
      - dev
      - sandbox
      - int
      - preprod
      - prod
    type: string
    displayName: "Environment"

stages:
  - stage: Configure${{ upper(parameters.env) }}
    displayName: "Configure Resources in ${{parameters.env}} 

    jobs:
      - job: Configure_${{ upper(parameters.env) }}
        pool:
          name: Project-Linuxpool
          demands:
            - Agent.Name -equals agent-$(environment)



How can I write the condition for dev and sandbox environment to use the same Agent.Name "agent-dev"?

You can use the if condition and the Or expression to let the dev and sandbox env to use the same agent.
Here is an example:
trigger: none

parameters:
  - name: env
    values:
      - dev
      - sandbox
      - int
      - preprod
      - prod
    type: string
    displayName: "Environment"

stages:
  - stage: Configure${{ upper(parameters.env) }}
    displayName: "Configure Resources in ${{parameters.env}}"

    jobs:
      - job: "Configure_${{ upper(parameters.env) }}"
        pool:
          name: Project-Linuxpool
          ${{if or(eq( parameters.env, 'dev'), eq( parameters.env,'sandbox') )}}:
           demands:
             - Agent.Name -equals agent-dev
          ${{ else }}:
           demands:
             - Agent.Name -equals agent-${{parameters.env}}      

When you select dev or sandbox in env parameters, it will use the dev agent. Or it will select the agent name based on the env parameters value.

I am getting below error while running the pipeline -
"(Line: 145, Col: 11): 'demands' is already defined"

@lzzy It seems that you are missing indentation for the demands field. You can check it and if the problem persists, you can update the question to share the latest yaml code

Thanks for your help, The issue is resolved now post correcting the Indentation. Really appreciate your effort. :)
